# GlassFish 4 (EJB3) - stateless bean lifecycle

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

According to [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-intro007.htm#GIPLJ) there are two states of stateless EJB: doesnt-exists and ready. But that's all it says about lifecycle.

I use glassfish 4 and I need to know exactly

1. when stateless EJB instance is created - at moment when domain started or when I inject my EJB to some point or?
2. when non used stateless EJB is destroyed - at moment when domain stopped or after some idle time or?

Please, help me.

Comment: Hi, I cannot tell you glassfish specifics, but did you try to play with annotations @PostConstruct, @PreDestroy?

Comment: @Matej Briškár Hi! It seems to me that GF create stateless beans when you call them (for example when trying to inject them). But I can't understand when and with what conditions they are destroyed.

Comment: @Matej Briškár I think that PashaTurok is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's necessary to read the following glassfish settings from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2431/abeea.html :

The EJB pool settings are:

**Initial and Minimum Pool Size:** the initial and minimum number of beans maintained in the pool. Valid values are from 0 to MAX_INTEGER, and the default value is 8. The corresponding EJB deployment descriptor attribute is steady-pool-size.

Set this property to a number greater than zero for a moderately loaded system. Having a value greater than zero ensures that there is always a pooled instance to process an incoming request.

**Maximum Pool Size:** the maximum number of connections that can be created to satisfy client requests. Valid values are from zero to MAX_INTEGER., and the default is 32. A value of zero means that the size of the pool is unbounded. The potential implication is that the JVM heap will be filled with objects in the pool. The corresponding EJB deployment descriptor attribute is max-pool-size.

Set this property to be representative of the anticipated high load of the system. An very large pool wastes memory and can slow down the system. A very small pool is also inefficient due to contention.

**Pool Resize Quantity:** the number of beans to be created or deleted when the cache is being serviced by the server. Valid values are from zero to MAX_INTEGER and default is 16. The corresponding EJB deployment descriptor attribute is resize-quantity.

Be sure to re-calibrate the pool resize quantity when you change the maximum pool size, to maintain an equilibrium. Generally, a larger maximum pool size should have a larger pool resize quantity.

**Pool Idle Timeout:** the maximum time that a stateless session bean, entity bean, or message-driven bean is allowed to be idle in the pool. After this time, the bean is destroyed if the bean in case is a stateless session bean or a message driver bean. This is a hint to server. The default value is 600 seconds. The corresponding EJB deployment descriptor attribute is pool-idle-timeout-in-seconds.

If there are more beans in the pool than the maximum pool size, the pool drains back to initial and minimum pool size, in steps of pool resize quantity at an interval specified by the pool idle timeout. If the resize quantity is too small and the idle timeout large, you will not see the pool draining back to steady size quickly enough.

Comment: How does this answer the question(s)? OP is asking specifically about the bean's lifecycle, not the pooling of EJBs